# concatenation challenge in html and jsp scriptlets with struts

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp, struts

```
<script>
   var myValue = ${valueBean};
</script>
```

The value of myValue is 5

`<input type="text" name="<%=curName%>'[' + myValue +'].otherList[' + myValue + '].'<%=curProp%>" value="<%=(String) currentItr.next()%>"/>`

When i view source, the generated html keeps giving me

```
<input type="text" name="myList'[' + myValue +'].otherList[' + myValue + '].'someProp" value="XXX"/>
```

when it should be

```
<input type="text" name="myList[5].otherList[5].someProp" value="XXX"/>
```

Am i doing something different, i cannot quite see where my concatenation problem is. please help!

Comment: You can't just embed javascript inside of html like that. Try using `document.write()` or some form of DOM manipulation.

Comment: And a third question of the same thing :(

Comment: @DaveNewton sorry mate, i don't like this practice either but it's legacy code i have to work with :(

Comment: @bouncingHippo My issue isn't with the code style (which is beyond horrible, and not fixing it is irresponsible) but that you've asked the same question three times with two users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<input type="text" name="<%=curName%>[${valueBean}].otherList[${valueBean}].<%=curProp%>" value="<%=(String) currentItr.next()%>"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

istead of using myValue you can use jstl and directly embedded valueBean using jstl c:out tag

```
name="myList'[' + myValue +'].otherList[' + <c:out value='${valueBean}'/> + '].'someProp"
```